# Using Gram-Schmidt to orthogonalize Matrix Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

$\newcommand\m[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}$
I have the billinear form $f(A,B) = trace(A*B)$ on $V = Mat(2x2,R)$. If I just start from the standard basis of $V$ then I end up with my second matrix in the Gram-Schmidt process being $v_2$ Which is clearly not orthogonal. What am I doing wrong?
$v_1 = \m{1&0\\0&0} \\ v_2 = \m{0&1\\0&0}-\frac{f(v_1,v_2)}{f(v_1,v_1)}*\m{1&0\\0&0} = \m{0&1\\0&0}$

Comment: why aren't $v_1$ and $v_2$ orthogonal with respect to the given norm?

Comment: Because $f(v_2,v_2)$ = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bilinear form should be: $f(A,B)= \mbox{tr} \; A^T B = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}b_{ij}$. Note that writing a 2 by 2 matrix as a 4-vector: $X_A=(a_{11}, a_{12},a_{21},a_{22})$ your (modified) bilinear form is simply the usual scalar product of $X_A$ with $X_B$. In your example, the standard matrix basis is in fact orthonormal for this scalar product.

Comment: I was given f(A,B)= trace(A*B) as the bilinear form though. Why should it be different?

Comment: Your $*$ looks like a multiplication sign. For complex matrices that is fine with the adjoint operation and the same as applying transpose when matrices are real. Note that $f(v_2,v_2)= \mbox{tr} \; v_4= 1$ which is what you wanted.

Comment: It is a multiplication sign.

Comment: Then it is wrong. It should be adjoint, $(A^*)_{ij} = \overline{A_{ji}}$ in order for this to define an inner product, so that for every non-zero $A$, $f(A,A)>0$.

Comment: Ah ok, so its not an inner product so I can't use gram-schmidt. What other way could I use to find an orthogonal basis for this Bilinear form?

Comment: What is the context? Because normally you would not use this bilinear form (because being degenerate). In Lie algebra theory one uses it but only on Lie algebra elements, for which it is non-degenerate.

Comment: The question im trying to answer is divided into three parts. First it says to find the Matrix of this bilinear form in respect to the standard basis. Then find the signature of the bilinear form. Then find an orthogonal basis for the bilinear form.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The matrix (4 by 4) of the bilinear form is symmetric and you may calculate it by hand, e.g. ${\rm tr}\; (v_2 v_3)=1$ etc... It's quite straight-forward. The corresponding metric has signature $(-1,1,1,1)$. To get an orthogonal basis (hint:) you need a part from $v_1$ and $v_4$ to look at $v_2\pm v_3$.